# Will ubuntu ever have an automatically updating release like chrome and iOS?

Tags: updates

I was wondering if ubuntu will ever be able to keep itself updated without user interaction like chrome boxes and iOS. I heard windows 10 is planning to be like this as well. Not sure if it would be practical for the ubuntu community. For instance my 14.04 automatically updating to the next LTS without my needing to approve anything. :D

Comment: It is not a good idea to upgrade automatically.

Comment: I hope they don't, automatic updates can be a real pain, what if there are bugs or experimental  features in the new release and you don't want or need them, Ubuntu / linux is about your choices and should stay so

Comment: Well maybe the choice could be to choose whether to automatically update or not. If i want to micromanage my updates like we currently do i just disable the auto update feature. otherwise I enable and let the distributors take care of me from this point forward. This way i can install it on my uncle's computer and if he only needs to browse the internet and check email with a browser no need to decide what updates he needs to install and it becomes as simple as a iPhone or chrome box. Guess I can just get him a chromebox and chuck his old windows based tower?

Answer (score 2):

Forcing updates is a bad idea. What if one doesn't work well with someones system, what if they have a really important deadline and the install screws up, blocking them from their PC until they sort it? Forcing updates introduces a lack of control.

With a standard configuration updates are only a click away. With the standard update manager, security updates can be set to be automatic. For automating more upgrades you can use the `unattended-upgrades` package, with control over which packages update. Perhaps one day `unattended-upgrades` will have a nice GUI which to my knowledge it doesn't yet.

As for actually doing distro-upgrades that is the sort of thing you really want to ask people about first. Are you happy with your GUI changing, some packages perhaps not being supported, and a really the update taking a long time? But still that can be only a click away.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu supports automatic installation of minor software updates.  My install notes say to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

and "select the 'yes' option" (you may need to install it, but my experience is that it is already installed, so you just need to reconfigure it).  I believe that only handles security updates, but more detailed config is available in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

As far as automatic release-upgrades, (e.g. between 12.04 and 14.04), I'll echo others' statements that you probably don't want to do those automatically.  Those actually *often* break and change things (even for just simple GUI use).  For server use, you damn well want to make sure the new system works when that happens; for "older relative" use, it's probably good to be on-hand to do any tech support that might be needed - do you remember how significantly the UI changed from 10.04 to 12.04?  Besides, you really only want LTS releases in that case, and those only happen once every 2 years!

Answer (score 0):

Forcing updates without permmision is a terrible idea, it would result in ( anyway i think) 90 percent of the ubuntu population being very frustrated, ubuntu is built for the user, not the company to make money